# Is it possible to pull data from a https:// url by passing the date parameters

Tags: shell, https, informatica

I have a requirement where I need to automate my current informatica(Informatica installed on Linux) workflow process. Through ages, the source files were manually downloaded from the vendor's web portal which looks something like https://portal.name.com, then enter the credentials to login into the website. Later, they go to the place where the reports(source files) can be downloaded as .xls format and then they format the files using a excel macro and save it as .csv. We then use this .csv file to load data in our workflows.

So I was wondering if any part of the process can be automated like for downloading the files? I was able to convert most of the macro part into shell script but need help with downloading the files, converting the .xls file to .csv file...

Comment: It's not really an Informatica question. Check the `curl` tool to download the files.

Comment: I tagged Informatica because I thought people working on Informatica might have come across the same situation, so they might be able to help... Thanks for your suggestion about the curl tool... I will check it out...

Comment: This (i.e. finding users with exact same problem) works for popular tags but [tag:informatica] is not one of them. My suggestion is to split it into a few separate questions: how to download a file from a portal that requires logon, how to convert Excel to CSV in Linux, etc.